# How to get Navigation bar inside UIPopover Controller

Tags: ipad, ios5

I am using a uipopover controller with navigation bar.Actually i want to have navigation bar inside the popover controller. i tried changing the background color of the navigation controller but it didnt look as i expected.The navigation bar buttons seems to be attached with the popover corners.Please find the screenshot attached.Below is my code which i used to create the popover.

WLViewBookmarkViewController * viewBookmarkViewController = [[WLViewBookmarkViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

viewBookmarkViewController.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *viewBookmarkNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewBookmarkViewController];

viewBookmarkNavController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:9/255.0 green:135/255.0 blue:46/255.0 alpha:1.0];

self.bookmarkPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewBookmarkNavController];

[self.bookmarkPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:bookmarkButtonItem                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown|UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                                   animated:YES];

```
    Please suggest if there are any other way to achieve this.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Xib in where i had a view for the controller which i had to add inside the popover.i added a table view and a navigation bar into the view.

Answer (score 0):

I would init the UIPopover controller with the UINavigationController directly

```
self.bookmarkPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: viewBookmarkNavController];
```

Also try settings the content size of the popover by overriding `-contentSizeForViewInPopover` in the viewBookmarkViewController class to return a CGSize, you should get neater results this way.